# Координаты с maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Создал гугл карту. Можно ли используя `googlemapsapi` при клике по карте узнавать координаты места куда кликнул курсором мыши?  Как на самих гугл картах когда задерживаешь на 2 секунды левую кнопку мыши. Показывается окно с адресом и координатами.

```
function addMap() {
    require(['https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCtSFwATUb4p2pSC9QEmbERxq5QmV9IjbM'], function () {

        var uluru = {lat: 55.758125,  lng: 37.613703};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 17,
          center: uluru
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно добавить listener на карту.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
   var lat = event.latLng.lat();
   var lng = event.latLng.lng();
});
```

Comment: Спасибо! Очень помогли